# How to detect only one value from Google Vision QR Scanner?

Tags: android, firebase, qr-code, barcode-scanner, google-vision

I have implemented a QR scanner(QRScanner class) using Google Vision API. Once a value is detected it is passed to another activity(Info class) using Intents. The problem is that once a QR code is scanned the Info class gets opened several times.I want to limit the QRScanner class to get only one QR value and Info classed to be opened only once.

**QRScanner Class**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_qr_scanner);

    cameraPreview = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.camera_surface);
    qrResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scannerResult);
    setupCamera();
}

private void setupCamera() {

    BarcodeDetector barcodeDetector = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(this).setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.QR_CODE).build();
    final CameraSource cameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(this, barcodeDetector)
            .setAutoFocusEnabled(true)
            .setRequestedPreviewSize(1600, 1024)
            .build();

    cameraPreview.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(QrScanner.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
            try {
                cameraSource.start(cameraPreview.getHolder());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            cameraSource.stop();
        }
    });


    barcodeDetector.setProcessor(new Detector.Processor<Barcode>() {
        @Override
        public void release() {

        }

        @Override
        public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<Barcode> detections) {

            final SparseArray<Barcode> qrCodes = detections.getDetectedItems();

            if(qrCodes.size()>0)
            {
                qrResult.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        qrResult.setText(qrCodes.valueAt(0).displayValue);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(QrScanner.this,Info.class);
                        intent.putExtra(QR_CODE,qrCodes.valueAt(0).displayValue);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**Info Class**

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
    QRCODE = (String) intent.getStringExtra(QrScanner.QR_CODE);

    DB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    ref = DB.getReference().child("Animals").child(QRCODE);
    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            String DBAnimalClass = dataSnapshot.child("class").getValue().toString();
            String DBAnimalFamily = dataSnapshot.child("family").getValue().toString();
            String DBAnimalOrder = dataSnapshot.child("order").getValue().toString();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

**Currently once a QR is detected the Info class gets called several times. I want the QRScanner to get only one value and Info class to get called only once**

Comment: Please don't add [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54683291/how-to-set-google-vision-qr-scanner-to-detect-only-one-value) questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set Google Vision QR Scanner to detect only one value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54683291/how-to-set-google-vision-qr-scanner-to-detect-only-one-value)

Answer (score 0):

before go to activity, you need to release BarCodeDetector. Use `barcodeDetector.release()` before to call `Runnable`